# Favourite dynamic content in android using preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, preferenceactivity

I am developing a news paper application. I populate the news as listview in home page and if the user click on a particular list that will redirect to that detail view. If the user wants to store that in favourites what they do? Is there a way to store that. Help me please.
By Babu.

Answer (score 0):

You should store some reference that you can recognize to that particular article.